# HTML+CSS:Is there a way to have a container(modal) in "vacuum" from the rest of the page so no other styling applied to it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I have downloaded a free bootstrap template which has a lot of pages with a lot of styles and scripts.

When I try to add an html container to that page(which is a modal/popup), all the styles from body to headers apply to it which breaks it completely.

So because I don't want to create a class/id for all and some width/heights on the parent and body divs styling are impossible to avoid without breaking the template flow, I am wondering if there is a way to create a html container with some option that if you add it, absolutely no other styling applies to it and I can style it as I wish irrespective of what happens around it?

Could z-index work here?

**L.EDIT**
I have added the code here on codepen `[codepen modal][1]`[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/t_andrei/pen/poyrXpb)

The modal should look like in the codepen but instead it is spread out like it is here in this screenshot.[image]

Comment: z index only indicates what depth an element will be placed on a page. All other styles will be inherited. You'll probably need to put a class on your modal that sets all the css that needs to be overridden. An iframe would ignore all other css on the page, but it's not great design to use an iframe because you're having trouble with your theme.

Comment: please add a demo in [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or add html and css code.

Comment: i have added what you have requested

Comment: Have you tried using CSS with higher specificity as provided here in the updated version of your [codepen](https://codepen.io/richierich25/pen/VwaMZXW)?

Comment: yes i am doing that since nothing else that i tried works, but is a rather slow and tedious process, that is why i was asking if there exist some code that could do that more easely.

Answer (score 1):

Your styling for your custom element must be of higher specificity than the other styling that is declared. Take a look at this great article by Emma Bostian :

[https://dev.to/emmabostian/css-specificity-1kca#:~:text=CSS%20Specificity%20is%20the%20set,present%20on%20the%20element's%20style](https://dev.to/emmabostian/css-specificity-1kca#:%7E:text=CSS%20Specificity%20is%20the%20set,present%20on%20the%20element%27s%20style).

Answer (score 0):

There's a following property in CSS:

```
#Element {
   all: initial;
}
```

This should reset all the styling from the parent elements including the container in which the element is placed and the body.

Try this and declare the styles after.

Comment: so i added this #modalContainer{all:initial;} in <style> head but nothing happens, am i doing something wrong?